# ReactJs Include component inside another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component/page that goes like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
);

export default About;
```

and a second one where I'm be adding a slider:

```
import React from 'react';

const Slider = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Slider</h2>
    <p>Slider Goes here</p>
  </div>
);

export default Slider;
```

What I need to do is the include the slider component at the bottom of the About component above so that when I display the About component the slider comes up too.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this

```
import React from 'react';
import Slider from 'path/to/Slider';

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
    <Slider />
  </div>
);

export default About;
```

[React - Composing Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components)